# Create an interval - Base R

Tags: r, intervals

I would like to create a single interval without using the `cut` function.  For example, given integers `a` and `b` an interval `(a,b]` can be created by calling `cut(c(a, 2 * b - a), 2)[1]`:

```
a <- 2.10
b <- 2.15
intervals = cut(c(a, 2 * b - a), 2)
intervals[1]
#> [1] (2.1,2.15]
#> Levels: (2.1,2.15] (2.15,2.2]
```

How can I create `(a,b]` without this workaround? I haven't been able to find any documentation for intervals outside of the documentation for the `cut` and `findInterval` functions.

Comment: If you use `cut(x, breaks=vec)`, then it finds the intervals among `vec` for each of `x`. For instance, `cut(seq(0, 1, length = 11), c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: But what if I want just the interval (0,1]?  If I call `cut(c(0,1), c(0,1), include.lowest = FALSE)` I get `c(NA, (0,1])`.  I'd like to get just `(0,1]`.

Comment: You get the `NA` because your first 0 is ***not*** inside `(0,1]`, since the left is *open* (forced by your intentional use of `include.lowest=FALSE`). If you use `include.lowest=TRUE` (as I did first), then you get `[0,1] [0,1]`. You will never see `0` within `(0,1]`, it is mathematically inconsistent.

Comment: Yep, I understand that; but if I try `cut(c(.Machine$double.eps, 1), c(0,1))`, I get `(0,1] (0,1]`.  Is there not way to get a single value of `(0,1]` as a response?

Comment: If you put in a vector of length 2, then you will get a vector out of length 2. The purpose of the same-length output is so that *each* value of the output corresponds to *each* value of the input. If you want just one value in the result, then (a) you are discarding that correspondence, and (b) you can do that with `unique(cut(...))`. While this is not guaranteed to give you a single output, it gives you only one of each "bin" found in your input. If you always want just one and don't care about losing information, do `head(cut(...), n=1)`.

Comment: I apologize if I'm mis-understanding your question.

Comment: Stupid question from me: is there a difference between an 'interval' returned by ```cut``` and a factor of a character vector of the form ```"(2.1,2.5]"```?  In other words, do the 'interval's have some additional property that isn't conferred by simply creating the character vector ```myinterval=paste0("(",2.1,",",2.15,"]")```?  Using the example in zack's question, ```myinterval==intervals[1]``` seems to return ```TRUE```...

Comment: The labels that `cut` returns are just `factor`s/strings; try adding `labels=FALSE` or `labels=c("A","B")` (if two bins) to see what I mean. So perhaps the answer you are looking for: no, you cannot generate a vector like `c("(0,1]","(1,5]","(5,100]")` and use it as-is; instead, you'd use `cut(..., c(0,1,5,100))` and get those labels as output.

Comment: Thank you for all your recommendations.  What I'm trying to get at is that it seems odd to me that we cannot create intervals outside of `cut`.  I understand the use case of `cut`, but I also see a use case for instantiating a single interval (e.g. checking to see if a specific interval is within a larger vector of intervals returned by `cut`).  To me, using `cut(...)[1]` to get an interval is like using `seq(0,1,length.out=2)[2]` to obtain a double type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - I'll admit that I haven't completely understood the full utility of this, but here's a suggestion how you could do it.

Since the 'intervals' returned by `cut` are nothing but character vectors, you can construct them using your variables `a` and `b`, and use them to test to see if a particular interval-of-interest is present within the output of `cut`.

Example:
First make some intervals to search within:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata=sample(1:100,20)
mycutintervals=cut(mydata,7)
mycutintervals
```

Now construct intervals-of-interest to check if these are present:

```
make_interval=function(x,y) paste0("(",x,",",y,"]")

a=19
b=32
# is interval from a to b present?
make_interval(a,b) %in% mycutintervals
# [1] TRUE

c=50
# what about interval from a to c?
make_interval(a,c) %in% mycutintervals
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This clears up my confusion about the intervals - I don't often work with factors outside of dataframes, so I was confused when I saw that `typeof(cut(c(0,1),2)[1])` was `integer` and not `character`. I assumed that the intervals returned by `cut` were more than just factors.

This question arose while writing a unit test for a function that returns a set of intervals.

Comment: I'm now seeing the fastest way to create a single interval `(a,b]` is not `cut(c(a +.Machine$double.eps, b), c(a,b))[1]`.  The fastest way is simply `factor("(a,b]")`.

Comment: @zack - I'm not even sure that it's necessarily helpful to make your new single 'interval' a ```factor```, because its value (which will be 1) will probably be different from that of the same interval returned by a call to ```cut```.  This won't stop you from using its 'level' (the character string) to check for presence/absence, though.

Comment: Ah yes, good point.  In that case, supposing `int_vec` is a vector of intervals from which I'd like to create just one interval, I could use `factor("(a,b]", levels = levels(int_vec))`.  This would return `NA` if `(a,b]` is not in `int_vec`.

Comment: Yes, that would work (but I still can't think of a use where you couldn't simply use just a character vector...).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of options below can help

```
> cut(c(a,b),range(c(a-.Machine$double.eps,b)))
[1] (2.1,2.15] (2.1,2.15]
Levels: (2.1,2.15]
```

or

```
> na.exclude(cut(c(a,b),range(a,b)))
[1] (2.1,2.15]
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 1
attr(,"class")
[1] exclude
Levels: (2.1,2.15]
```